# Acclerate docker pull in China/Asia

Tags: docker

It is really slow when you are pulling images from official docker repository, uh, at China.

I am not asking for a working solution at local because I already found https://github.com/docker/docker-registry. What I am asking is if there is an alternative repository available and faster in China/Asia, just like many of them as Debian repository sources?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As I know,

dockerpull published their local repository, so you can simply put their host in front of the repository this way:

```
docker pull daocloud.io/ubuntu:14.04
```

And a more graceful way is to use registry mirror from daocloud, append below line to /etc/default/docker.io or /etc/default/docker

```
DOCKER_OPTS="$DOCKER_OPTS --registry-mirror=http://YOUR_ID.m.daocloud.io"
```

Please be noted that YOUR_ID need to be replaced by your registered ID, which is provided after you register an account on www.daocloud.io. So far the lunch is almost free, you got 10GB bandwidth monthly to go.

Answer (score 10):

There is an official mirror from docker in China.

https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/#use-case-the-china-registry-mirror

> You can add "https://registry.docker-cn.com" to the registry-mirrors
>   array in /etc/docker/daemon.json to pull from the China registry
>   mirror by default.
>
> `{   "registry-mirrors": ["https://registry.docker-cn.com"] }`

Comment: I tried this today, found that it's not working anymore.

Comment: ah yes, seems like it unfortunately: https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/8793

Comment: there are a couple of options for other mirrors at https://github.com/nwcdlabs/kops-cn/issues/110

Comment: Thanks for the mirror option share -- the ustc mirror works as of this post.

Answer (score 2):

As a Docker Toolbox user, you can create a docker machine with `--engine-registry-mirror https://registry.docker-cn.com` . eg.

```sh
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-registry-mirror https://registry.docker-cn.com dev
```

or add it in the docker machine settings in `~\.docker\machine\machines\<machine name>\config.json` like this.

```
"HostOptions": {
        //...
        "EngineOptions": {
        //...
            "RegistryMirror": [
                "https://registry.docker-cn.com"
            ],
            "InstallURL": "https://get.docker.com"
        },
```

other mirrors:

- [docker-cn](https://registry.docker-cn.com)
- [163](https://c.163.com/)
- [daocloud](https://daocloud.io)
- [alicloud](https://aliyuncs.com)
- [ustc](https://ustc.edu.cn)

Answer (score 0):

An update to this a good mirror is aliyun `registry.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [
    "https://hub-mirror.c.163.com",
    "https://mirror.baidubce.com"
  ]
}
```